# L1-Norm minimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to minimize the following function using Linear programming. I am unable to include the image of my objective function. Click this [Objective Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbE2H.png) to view what I am trying to optimize. My question is there any library or function in python which can do this optimization for me or should I be writing the code?

Comment: There are many LP solvers for Python. This is just one: [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

Comment: Looks lie linprog will solve my problem. But I know how to workaround linprog in matlab to solve the problem by calling linprog([zeros(m,1);ones(n,1)],[+A,-eye(n);-A,-eye(n)],[b;-b]). Do you know how I can do this with python? @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: Same thing. `sp.linprog(np.block([np.zeros(m),np.ones(n)]), np.block([[+A,-np.eye(n)],[-A,-np.eye(n)]]),np.block([b,-b]),bounds=n*[(None,None)]+m*[(0,None)] )`

Comment: Oh thank you. I forgot np.block I was using np.array. and np.eye is a good touch too. @ErwinKalvelagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N=10
M=100

U = np.random.random((M,N))
m = np.random.random(M)
t = cp.Variable(M)
x = cp.Variable(N)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum(t)), [-t<=U@x-m, U@x-m<=t])
optimal_value = prob.solve()
print("t=",t.value)
print("x=",x.value)
print("val=",optimal_value)
```

Comment: linprog solved my problem. But I will try your cvx method also. Thank you.

Comment: One question thought. What if my U is of dimension of M*N where M is not equal to N. Why the optimisation method throws a broadcasting error for that?

Comment: @MLLearner: Because you need to ensure the dimensionality of all of your vectors is correct. See edited answer.

Comment: @MLLearner: Happy to help. I'd encourage you to look into the other capabilities of `cvxpy`: it's considerably more powerful than an LP solver.

Comment: I am actually looking at it as of now. I am thinking of installing Mosek solver but its not open source anymore. CVX has solved so many of my issue and much faster than LP solver. Someone should do a good tutorial on CVX for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

There is the minimization method for the scipy library's optimization method. I am unsure how you would go about finding the L1-Norm but perhaps this will help with the minimization.

Each word listed in the () after minimize is a parameter. The "fun" parameter is the for a function and is where you'd put the L1-Norm after you've found it using another method.

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(
fun, x0, args=(), method='BFGS',
jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, 
constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None
)
```

Comment: This is not a linear programming solver but rather an unconstrained nonlinear solver/